# Search Suggestions Background

Tags: android, search

Hello I've just implemented a search option on my application use [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) on the Android developer site, which is working perfectly, and so I've added Search Suggestions, so when the user searches something it will be saved for next time, I've done [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html) using this tutorial on the Android Developer site too.

This works perfectly except for when you start typing and if what your typing isn't in the latest queries list then it hides query list so that the screen behind the search UI shows, But this looks really horrible and unattractive, i was wondering if I'm able to keep the white background even if the query isn't in the list?

Hope that makes sense, Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: I've noticed even the android market will do that... are you sure it's such a bad thing?

Comment: yes, because the home screen behind it gets squashed up :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would try to avoid the "squashing" is in the activity thats getting squashed set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" or android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in the activity tag in your manifest.

If thats the what your looking for you can always use your own search activity where you implement everything on your own. I have done this, and apps like twitter and facebook have also done this if you want to see some examples.